# Which acoustic guitar string gauge to buy as a beginner ({.009-.045},{.010-.050},{.011-.052})

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings, string-gauge

As I started to learn to play acoustic guitar, I broke 1st string e 2 times straight in a week.

Can anybody tell me which string is best for a beginner (by best expectation from the string is to be durable, produce nice sound and pocket-friendly)?

Comment: Visit a brick-n-mortar musical instruments store, and pick a bunch of string 1 and string 2 (the thinnest two). As a beginner, and on a guitar that doesn't hold tune well, you are going to break many of those as you are yet to develop a feel of the tension where is become apparent that strings may snap. At this stage brands are not likely to matter as much. For a beginner I'd stick to 9s and 10s (after few years of late life learning, I'm still using 10s). Unbranded strings bought from store are often inexpensive, compared to branded full-sets.

Comment: curious what gauge you had on there. if you broke it twice you must have replaced it at least once. are you sure you used the correct string for the one that you were replacing? are you sure you strung it correctly? did you use a tuner to tune it?

Comment: @b3ko Both the time i broke the string it was changed by vendor and i was told that it was ({.011-.052}), this time i am thinking to change by myself.
I am using guitarTuna to tune the guitar (please let me know if its good )

Comment: guitar tuna is fine as long as you are tuning the correct string to the correct pitch. if you have it in standard tuning, and "auto" it should be fine. just wanted to make sure you were not tuning it ridiculously tight. 11's should not be a problem for an acoustic guitar. is there anything where the string touches the guitar that may be sharp or rough? either in the nut slot, the bridge, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use 11's if you want the gauge to feel lighter. 11's are great because they are not too heavy but light enough for a begginer. I like to use 11's whenever I play, because that way I can also do lead stuff on the acoustic. Whether or not you will be doing that (which I assume not yet) 11's will obviously feel lighter then 12's and 10's on an acoustic may be too light.

Comment: I've used .008s and .009s for many years on acoustics, and found no problems for lead stuff.  Also, we don't know what guitar it is, or what strings were originally on the guitar (or should have been).

Answer (score 1):

just an ask are you perhaps tuning to high ?
I managed to do that as a beginner without an electronic tuner and broke several Ist strings before i realised 
I had gradually tuned the strings up over time using the manual way of tuning using the 6 string E as a referance .

check for any rough ends on the frets where your string is breaking ,could be a burr on a fret edge ,easily removed with needle file or similar

If your a new player ive also broken e strings by clumsy heavy strumming,so you may need to rail back on your strumming action,especially if u have light strings..pick should sweep in a curve away from you ,**not straight away at 90 degrees** across the strings,your pick hand should end up close to the top edge of the saddle after a downstroke,also the pick should meet the string at a slightly edge on angle,this will give less resistance and produce a sweeter tone

Answer (score 0):

It's very unusual to break the fat E string once, let alone twice. I suspect it was the high E, the 1st string. Acoustic guitars are often supplied with .011s or .012s, and without a means of measuring the string, it's not easy for you to determine. I use a caliper gauge, which gives an exact answer.

But maybe a more apposite point is why they keep breaking. That, I can't answer. Possibly you are playing too hard, or there is a problem with the guitar itself. Get in touch with the manufacturers. and pose the question - .011 or .012 will be the answer - and the difference is slight.

Myself, I'd go for something even lighter, but that's my choice. Lighter strings are less prone to breakage, despite what some say. Price won't vary much, but lighter strings will be easier to press, less likely to break, but not sound as rich as heavier gauge.

EDIT: I'm more concerned as to why the strings are breaking. Whether you have .007s or .014s, they shouldn't be breaking. It may be that you are still hazy as to how to tune properly. Try to find someone else who plays - a teacher is best - and go through the process with them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all other responses in relation to the likelihood of breaking that e string. Gauge wise I would suggest starting with 12s. They might hurt or feel too thick to begin with but it will pay off in the long run.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's good here if you can elucidate on statements made in answers. 'It will pay off in the long run'. Why? How?